# Is is possible to convert SQL Server from single instance to failover clustered node?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover

If SQL Server 2014 Enterprise has already been installed, can it still be converted/added to a failover cluster? Specific scenario - Amazon EC2 instance of Windows 2012 + SQL Server 2014 (license included).
Or is the only option an installation of a failover cluster node from scratch?

Comment: I assume you installed SQl Server 2014 in standalone mode if so you cannot change it to Cluster mode. You would have to uninstall the SQl Server and install it again selecting `New failover cluster`